# iOS API 2.0 Retrieving the XID

Tags: xtify

I am using the latest SDK for iOS and I have put the suggested code in init method of my appDelegate:

```
[[XLappMgr get] setInboxDelegate:self];
[[XLappMgr get]setDeveloperRegisterNotificationSelector:@selector(doSomethingAfterRegister:)];
[[XLappMgr get] setDeveloperXidNotificationSelector:@selector(doUpdateXid:)];
```

The doSomethingAfterRegister method is called successfully but not the doUpdateXid one.

My aim is to get the Xid value and I would like to know when is the right time to do this task.

Comment: Hi, would you please take a look at the sample app bundled with the SDK?  I was able to build it and the method was called successfully. Perhaps make sure your app is doing the same thing.